# performSelectorInBackground: causing crash with CocoaAsyncSocket

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I discovered performSelectorInBackground: a couple days ago, and I immediately knew a spot in my app where this would be perfect.

```
- (void)activate {

    waitForStartCode.text = @"Loading...";
    userNotifications.text = @"";
    timeRemaining.text = @"";
    [loadingNTP startAnimating];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(initializeEverything) withObject:nil];

}
```

This is called when my view is visible. Before, while the NTP time servers were being connected to using CocoaAsyncSocket, my app froze until this process was completed. I really want a loading view with an animated UIActivityIndicatorView.

Everything in the initializeEverything -(void) works fine, exept the NTP initialization using CocoaAsyncSocket.

```
[NetworkClock sharedNetworkClock];
```

I get a :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Even with my unskilled eye, I could tell that CocoaAsyncSocket was not meant to be run in the background.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: I'd use GCD in favour of performSelectorInBackground:. Many advantages, but here's one: GCD will sensibly create as many threads as appropriate, rather than creating a new thread every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CocoaAsyncSocket supports asynchronous networking. So in principle you do not need a background thread yourself to prevent your UI from freezing: CocoaAsyncSocket will handle communication in background for you.

I cannot say if you are using the framework in a "blocking" way or you are doing anything else that is making your UI block. But, as I said, in principle you do not need to manage a background thread yourself.

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder why CocoaAsyncSocket is not running asynchronously in this case...I'll further research.

Comment: if you show some more code, I can try an provide more help... try to find the method where the UI blocks...

Comment: This is where the UI freezes: [NetworkClock sharedNetworkClock];

Comment: check the `init` method inside `NetworkClock.m` -- there the thread halts. You could try and undefine `THREADING_DOESNT_WORK_SO_DONT_TRY_IT` and check whether the NSOperation based flow will behave better.

Comment: Interesting. I commented out everything accept     [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] addOperation:[[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                                  initWithTarget:self
                                                        selector:@selector(createAssociations)
                                                          object:nil]];

Comment: And it works. Does it asynchronously. I think it's working fine now. Weird!

Comment: Ok, now it's actually presenting the same crash as I described in my question with cocoaasyncsocket

Comment: not sure I understand completely. seems like ios-ntp is not multithread and thus not reliable. you might check `createAssociations` implementation for ways to make it UI-friendlier (like splitting it in chunks of execution and then scheduling each chunk on the main thread sequentially)... just an idea...